# Heroku / Which URL should I specify to point my server's Websocket port

Tags: javascript, url, heroku, playframework, websocket

I have a Javascript client that aims to point to my WebSocket port on my backend (Play Framework app).

I try to init the connection like this in my client:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://myHerokuDomain:9000/api/notifications/ws");
```

but obtain this error (in Safari console): `WebSocket network error: Refused connection`

I imagine that the port may be wrong, Heroku using its own.

How to check for the port that Heroku uses when setting my Play Framework application?

I'm pointing out that I enabled websockets on Heroku using Heroku CLI, as the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-labs-websockets) explains.

In dev mode, the whole works using:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/api/notifications/ws");
```

So my problem sounds to be really about the chosen URL.

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the URI to:

```
'ws://' + window.location.host + '/api/notifications/ws'
```

and it works.

Comment: Hey, I'm deploying my java websocket app on heroku. Everything is fine but I cannot connect to it using java client (which works if deployed on localhost) it gives `javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error`

Comment: I used `ws://localhost:8080/Dashboard/hello` while on local host and `ws://host_name/Dashboard/hello` on heroku deployment